# How to get first item of each tuple in a list / python

Tags: python, list, key

I've initialized a dict in python 3.3.3 like this one:

```
# dict with dates and name
my_dict = {'keyone': '2013-04-22', 'keytwo': '2013-04-25'}
```

I've sorted this dict reverse by values with the following snippet:

```
# sort reverse by value
my_list = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

# will output a list of tuples
[('keytwo', '2013-04-25'), ('keyone', '2013-04-22')]
```

Now I'm trying to get a list of the keys (first item of each tuple) in the same order:

```
# what I need
my_new_list = ['keytwo', 'keyone']
```

Hope someone can help me. It's very depressing and frustrative!

Lots of greetings,

felix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension:

```
my_new_list = [key for key, value in my_list]
```

Or just produce a list of keys in the first place:

```
my_new_list = sorted(index_dict, key=index_dict.get, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Used the second solution!

Comment: Do you need `key=index_dict.get` in the second example?  If you do need it, an alternative could be `sorted(index_dict.keys(), reverse=True)` which is less typing, and on python3 `.keys()` returns a generator so it shouldn't be memory inefficient.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Yes, `key=index_dict.get` is necessary. We want to sort the keys by their associated values, not by the keys themselves. Also, the `keys()` call isn't necessary, since iterating over a dict iterates over the keys, and on Python 3, `keys()` returns a view, not a generator.

Comment: Ah.  I didn't notice they were being sorted by value.  I suppose I should think before I make a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
new_list = map(operator.itemgetter(0),my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> my_dict = {'keyone': '2013-04-22', 'keytwo': '2013-04-25'}
>>> my_list = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
>>> my_new_list = [x[0] for x in my_list]
>>> my_new_list
['keytwo', 'keyone']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {'keyone': '2013-04-22', 'keytwo': '2013-04-25'}
>>> sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
['keytwo', 'keyone']
```